# SQL GROUPING on 2 fields to get the min value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have wrote complex query and getting a data as shown below :

```
+----+---------+-------+------------+
| ID | TYPE_ID | VALUE | SORT_ORDER |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
|  1 |       1 | AAA   |          1 |
|  1 |       1 | BBB   |          2 |
|  2 |       1 | AA1   |          1 |
|  3 |       1 | BB2   |          1 |
|  3 |       1 | AA2   |          2 |
|  3 |       1 | BB3   |          3 |
|  4 |       2 | AAA1  |          1 |
|  4 |       1 | BB4   |          2 |
|  4 |       1 | AA4   |          3 |
|  5 |       2 | BB5   |          1 |
|  5 |       2 | AA5   |          2 |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
```

but I want to get the value for each ID with minimum sort_order and also consideing the Type_id 1 as higher priority. my group by is fetching above table for `Min(sort_order)` since I am including the Value in group by which is different for each row. Below is the expected result.

```
+----+---------+-------+------------+
| ID | TYPE_ID | VALUE | SORT_ORDER |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
|  1 |       1 | AAA   |          1 |
|  2 |       1 | AA1   |          1 |
|  3 |       1 | BB2   |          1 |
|  4 |       1 | BB4   |          2 |
|  5 |       2 | BB5   |          1 |
+----+---------+-------+------------+
```

Please give me your suggestions to achieve this.

Comment: Is the top example what your table looks like, or the result of your query?  Can we see your table structure?

Comment: Hi Tom,Top result is the result set of a query I am storing in a temporary table . There are several table involved to get this result set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server 2005+, the easiest way to get the result would be to use windowing functions. In this case you could use [`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and partition the data by `id` but sort the data by `type_id` and `sort_order`:

```
;with cte as
(
  select id, type_id, value, sort_order,
    rn = row_number() over(partition by id order by type_id, sort_order)
  from yourtable
)
select id, type_id, value, sort_order
from cte
where rn = 1
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/511cf/3). Once you've added the `row_number()` then you will only return the rows where the row number = 1.

Comment: @Piyush Does the answer you accepted actually return the correct result for `id = 4`?

Comment: No for that I corrected the sequence in partition.But other wise it gave me an idea on how to do.

Comment: @Piyush why don't you then accept this answer? (that gives correct results and has the same idea, i.e. `ROW_NUMBER()`)